Should the vote lock-in time period be increased?
Too often it seems to happen, that there is an answer that describes in detail a procedure which requires re-booting the computer at the end.  To re-boot computer, I have to close all windows, and all the steps were well-documented, so I vote the answer as good before closing everything down.  However, after re-booting the fix did not work.  I go to remove my up-vote, but it says, Sorry, 6 minutes have already elapsed.  And apparently I'm not the only one -- since that answer has a bunch of up-votes, and looking through where the post-reboot issue comes up more carefully, there is absolutely no way it can work, for anyone.  I would even down-vote it, but I can not now.
Another scenario, I am looking through a question, and an answer that works is at the top; so I upvote it.  However, I keep reading down the thread, and eventually I find an answer that not only has the solution, but also explains why it works.  I wish to switch my up-vote to the other answer, but my vote for the first answer is locked in.  And looking at the trend for several months, this top answer keeps getting more upvotes because it's at the top, and the better answer is 3-4 answers down below it.
A third situation, someone posts a superficial answer to a question, and I down-vote it because it's of poor quality.  4 minutes later, they update their answer, and it's actually the best answer now.  I wish to remove my downvote, but I don't notice their modification until another couple minutes have passed.  Because their edit was within the 5-minute grace period, it doesn't count as an edit -- but now, my down-vote is locked in.
The reason this issue occurs a lot is, because when I post an answer, I keep track of how many minutes have passed, to make sure I can submit my edit in time so others don't see that I posted a poorer answer just to be the first one in.  However, when you upvote, there is no expectation that I will have to change my vote within 5 minutes, so I don't keep track of how many minutes have passed: I just refresh the page periodically, and read what has been posted.
14 years ago, Jeff increased the time limit to change your vote up to 5 minutes; as justification, he gave that there are 3 exploits which can be performed using the ability to undo.  However, he did not provide any details, and he is no longer around (or so I heard) to assess whether the 5 minute limit is still necessary to curb these exploits.
Is it possible to increase the vote lock-in time to, say, at least 15 minutes?  This way, if I update the page every 10 minutes (= 15 minutes total minus 5 minutes grace), I still have a chance to change my vote if the answer has been edited within the grace period.
Based on the last attempt to increase this limit that I found, 13 years ago, this really seems like a popular suggestion, since 58 people agreed that the 5 minute limit is fair, and 149 voted that it's way too short, with at least 16 people (judging by the number of upvotes on the question) abstaining.  Obviously, I don't know what those exploits are, but I would think that now, 13 years later, the technology is so much more updated, that those exploits might have another way of curbing them.

The reason I can't wait is because I have to exit out of the browser in order to re-start the computer (which has 20+ tabs open).  It'll take a long time to find that page afterwards in history, if I wish to vote on it afterwards.  Hence the approach, vote on it now, and find it afterwards only if absolutely necessary.

I know it's okay to up-vote both answers, but the goal should be for the better answer to rise to the top.  As long as everyone who up-votes the second answer also up-votes the first answer, this will not happen, since the difference in the score between the first answer second answers will not decrease.

I understand that I should not do it.  However, if someone else does it, and their answer ends up being the best answer out there, I would like to be able to up-vote it.

Regarding "use the Save This Question feature" -- yes, it is doable, but it requires a bit of extra work.  And again, me doing this will not help solve the problem, which is the fact that this answer is at the top, despite not working for anyone.  Everyone else who upvoted was not able to roll their up-vote back either.

@Alex can you explain why you can't wait six minutes before voting? Try first, if it works, upvote. If it doesn't, downvote. Can't be more simple than that.

I regularly have more than 20 tabs open in just one window. And multiple such windows. However, I have no trouble recovering them - I restore my last session when starting the browser. There are also bookmarks and (on the SE network) saves for when I want to come back to a specific page or (on the SE network) a post. I agree it's a slight inconvenience but on the other hand it's a correct solution. Moving to 15 minutes won't solve the issue because people would have a problem changing their vote 16 minutes later. I personally find that it's rare I'd come back 6-15 minutes after voting.

@VLAZ For me, most of my re-considerations tend to be 6-8 minutes later.  Like, more-than-half type of most.  I just proposed 15 minutes because conceivably it might take more than 10 minutes to read through a long enough list of answers to a question.  The idea is, I upvote good answers as I read them, but if there is a more comprehensive answer down the list, I go back and un-upvote the first answer, to allow the latter answer to rise to the top quicker.

@VLAZ It doesn't make sense to have to keep a mental list of good answers to up-vote after reading all of them, because a person like me tends to forget which answers I meant to up-vote after reading enough of them.

OK, so, after reading a list of suggestions that don't rely on memory, your retort is that it doesn't work for you because you have to keep a mental list. Did you mean that as an example of why you really shouldn't rely on your memory? If not, I remain unconvinced that I should stop using my offload-my-memory-to-tech solutions. Neither do I find your time limit works for me. When I come back to something I've voted on, it's often 15+ minutes later because I usually vote, then go do other stuff - in another tab or not even on SE. Then come back later.

(In my opinion) No, it shouldn't. You shouldn't "vote an answer as good" (upvote) before you know if it is indeed useful. If 2 or more answers are good (even if one is better) you should upvote both of them. You're third situation is (I'd imagine) quite rare, that someone edits a low quality answer into a high quality one at just in the time range that it's under 5 minutes but you don't have time to change your vote. Increasing the time would simply make that time range a different range, not solve the issue.
"I posted a poorer answer just to be the first one in" - Is totally wrong, don't do that, especially when doing things "so others don't see that". The system is (for good reason) not designed to support things you shouldn't do.
